# Can the linker optimize and prevent functions to be pulled in the binary if they won't get called at runtime?

Tags: c++, optimization, linker

I am building a library which will be used to write different types of applications. The purpose of the library is to handle ways of startup. In short, the library implements the entry points. Depending on the type of application, my library will govern the startup journey.

However, I do not want the code for one type of application to be linked in for another type of application. The type of application is governed by the Application.cpp file. Following is a rudimentary visualization of what I am trying to achieve.

Application.hpp

```
#pragma once

class Application {

public:

static constexpr bool GetFlag () {return sFlag;}
static const     bool sFlag; // This is const and not constexpr, hence the GetFlag function gives error
};
```

main.cpp (This is the file that will be built as a library)

```
#include "Application.hpp"

void Func1 (); // Defined in a cpp file which will be compiled with main.cpp into main.lib
void Func2 (); // Defined in a cpp file which will be compiled with main.cpp into main.lib

int main ()
{
    if constexpr (Application::GetFlag ())
        Func1 ();
    else
        Func2 ();

    return 0;
}
```

For application of type 1:

Application.cpp:

```
#include "Application.hpp"

const bool Application::sFlag = true;
```

For application of type 2:

Application.cpp:

```
#include "Application.hpp"

const bool Application::sFlag = false;
```

My main.cpp gets generated into main.lib. This lib is used to link with various types of applications. The types of applications are governed by Application.cpp which is linked with main.lib to generate exe.

However, I do not want Func1 to be present in binary for application of Type 2 and Func2 to be present in binary for application of Type 1.

The current code gives a compilation error since sFlag is not a constexpr (and I can't make it a constexpr since it will be defined later).

It is guaranteed that sFlag will be a compile time definition but can vary for various types of application. I do not want to recompile main.lib for each type of application (since the only thing different for each type of application is the Application.cpp).

If I remove the constexpr keyword (both in Application.hpp and main.cpp), the 'if' check in main.cpp becomes a runtime check and the linker will pull in both Func1 and Func2 into the binary.

Is there any way to prevent that without changing Application.hpp for every application type (and hence recompiling main.lib)?

Is there any other way with which I can achieve both:

1. Prevent inclusion of unnecessary functions in the binary, and
2. Prevent recompilation of main.lib again and again for each application type?

I am building with MSVS compiler for Windows and clang for Linux.

Comment: How will you distribute your library? Will you allow your clients to compile it? If so - it would allow to if/def some parts of it that is not needed.

Comment: The library is for internal purpose. The reason of creating a library is to prevent recompilation. If I use preprocess directives, I will first need to compile with one set of values for one application type, then compile it again with another set of different values for second application type.

Answer (score 1):

This is not mandated by the standard, so the question should rather be: *can MY linker do that?*

But yes, this is a common feature.

In MSVC, the option is `/OPT:REF`, in gcc `-Wl,--gc-sections` I believe.

Additional compile time options ensure this happens per function (rather than per-clusters-of-function), in MSVC the option is `/Gy` (Enable Function-level Linking)

Removing unused code is actually expensive at link stage, so you usually want that enabled only for optimized release builds.

---

Link-Time Optimization is another common option that, besides better optimizations across source files, can improve size of the resulting binary.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional approach is to put each function in a separate source file, compile them all, and put them into a library. As the name suggests, the library contains resources, and the linker will pick out the ones that it needs.

Compilers may have options that let you do essentially the same thing without separate source files.